# Changing System Colors

Tags: winforms, powershell, colors, highlight, systemcolors

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

I am using `PowerShell` to build a GUI and I would like to override default system colors.

For example, when a control is highlighted (`TextBox` or `ComboBox`), form shows system colors. I would like to change the color to use `AliceBlue`. So far I have tried following codes, but to no avail:

```
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Highlight = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::HighlightText = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::ScrollBar = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Control = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::HotTrack = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::Window = 'AliceBlue'
[System.Drawing.SystemColors]::WindowFrame = 'AliceBlue'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx) says that those properties you are trying to set are readonly.

You can do this by invoking the `user32.dll` `SetSysColors` function:

```
$signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetSysColors(
    int cElements, 
    int [] lpaElements,
    uint [] lpaRgbValues);
'@

$type = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature `
                 -Name Win32Utils `
                 -Namespace SetSysColors `
                 -PassThru

$color = [Drawing.Color]::AliceBlue
# For RGB color values: 
# $color = [Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,255,255) 
$elements = @('13')
$colors = [Drawing.ColorTranslator]::ToWin32($color)

$type::SetSysColors($elements.Length, $elements, $colors)
```

Where the `13` element represents `COLOR_HIGHLIGHT`, which is the colour of an item selected in a control.

---

After running the above code, here is the result:

#### ComboBox

[image]

#### TextBox

[image]

---

You can see that the colour of the actual text has changed and it is barely visible. To change this, simply run:

```
$color = [Drawing.Color]::Black
$elements = @('14')
$colors = [Drawing.ColorTranslator]::ToWin32($color)
$type::SetSysColors($elements.Length, $elements, $colors)
```

Where `14` represents `COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT`, which is the colour of the text of an item selected in a control.

To see more about `SetSysColors` check [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetSysColors.html). Also, go [here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/coredll/SetSysColors.html) to find more color codes.

---

I don't know if it is possible to set the highlight colour for only the PowerShell GUI and nothing else using `WinForms` or `SetSysColor`, but one way you might consider is by using a `WPF` `TextBox` instead of `WinForms`. This way you can use `SelectionBrush` and `SelectionOpacity`:

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" 
       Title="Initial Window" 
       WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" 
       ResizeMode="NoResize"
       SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" 
       ShowInTaskbar = "True" 
       Background = "lightgray"> 
    <StackPanel >  
        <Label Content='Type in this textbox' />
        <TextBox x:Name="InputBox" 
                    Height = "50" 
                    SelectionBrush= "Green"
                    SelectionOpacity = "0.5" />  
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )


$Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Dear Bassie, Thank you very much for all your help in a short time. You have a great rest of the week!

Comment: Dear Bassie, there is a problem when running above code. Code changes required color, but the code has effect to complete OS. For example, when I open Notepad and highlight a text, I can see AliceBlue color. Is there any way to restrict color to the Winform? Thank You

Comment: @NickPrice Hi Nick, I added another possible solution to my answer, but it requires that you use a `WPF` `TextBox`. Hope that helps

Comment: Dear Bassie, I tried your WPF code, but it gives error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" at $Window.ShowDialog(). By the way, is there any way to override system colors by using WPF code that I could use in my PowerShell form? Thanks once again for your valuable input. - Thank You

Comment: Basically it says " ERROR: Unable to find type [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: @NickPrice As far as I know, you will need a `wpf` form to perform `wpf` operations on it. The reason why you get the error is because you don't have the `Windows.Markup.XamlReader` type loaded to your system.